# Error: setContentView(R.layout.main) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm developing a simple app for learning purpose, In which there is a single check box and a text line, which shows it is checked or unchecked. But it shows an error in line `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and `cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check)` this is my java code:

```
package com.example.kaushal.checkbox;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.R;

public class Checkbox extends Activity
    implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    CheckBox cb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            cb.setText("This checkbox is: checked");
        }
        else {
            cb.setText("This checkbox is: unchecked");
        }
    }
}
```

It is not a duplicate question,I've seen the answers of the same questions but it was all for eclipse.I'm working with android studio.

This is my xml layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   tools:context=".Checkbox">


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This checkbox is: unchecked" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm new to android so please guide me.

Comment: what exactly is your error? It does not recognise the id's properly?

Comment: show your layout xml.

Comment: it shows `can not resolve symbol 'main'`

Comment: Try to Clean Project and Rebuild from the Build Menu\

Comment: See the layout xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by my self. I thing the error is not because of wrong import as answered here. It was because of the use of wrong `name` and `id` of layout file and `check box` respectively. My `.xml` layout file name was `activity_my_checkbox.xml`. So I should use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_checkbox);
```

And my check box id was `c` instead of `check`, so I should use

```
cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong:

```
import android.R;
```

You didn't import your own R file, try to import your <package>.R, maybe `com.example.kaushal.R`, not android.R.

Comment: Which is my package here?

Comment: you can see your package name in manifest.xml,if it's `com.exmaple.kaushal`,you should import `com.example.kaushal.R`.

Comment: first check whether your resource file has error,if so,try to fix it,then try to clean project and rebuild.

Comment: Which is resource file?

Comment: @KaushalShah,that files and views and attrs will generate R.id.xxx,R.layout.xxx,R.anim.xxx

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.R;
import android.R.layout;
```

Clean your project and rebuild it again.

Comment: It shows 'import android.R.layout;' is an unused import.

Answer (score 0):

you import your package name and than R file. like that

import com.example.kaushal.checkbox.R;

and than rebuild your project.

```
import com.example.kaushal.checkbox.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

instead of `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Answer (score 0):

I am solving this issue in a simple step:

go to file,
select invalid cache/restart,
choose invalid cache/restart.

wait for a minute...

Comment: IMO, it should not be an answer to this question. It should go as a comment.